# Matching images based on timestamps acquired from two different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

For a project I am working on I am using two different threads to acquire images from different hardware on a Windows system using Opencv and C++. For the purposes of this post we will call them camera1 and camera2. Due to varying frame rates I cannot capture both from both camera1 and camera2 on the same thread or try to capture one image at a time. Instead, I have buffers set up for both cameras. Camera1 runs at over double the frame rate of camera2.

A third thread gets a frame from camera2 and tries to match that to an image taken by camera1 at the nearest point in time. The problem I am having is that I can't find a good way to match an image from one source to an image that was acquired at roughly the same time in the other source.

Is there a method of assigning time stamps to these images that is accurate when used in separate threads that are not high priority? If not, is there another design method that would be better suited to a system like this.

I have had a hard time finding any information as to how far off methods of keeping track of time in Windows like clock() and queryperformancecounter are when used in separate threads on different CPUS. I have read that they are not accurate when used in separate threads, but I am acquiring frames at roughly 20 frames per second so even if they are off, it may be close enough to still work well.

Thank you in advance! Let me know if I should clear anything up or explain better.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately I don't think there is any way for me to get timestamps from the drivers or the hardware. I think I have figured out a way to pretty accurately determine when an image is actually captured relative to each thread though. The part I don't really know how to deal with is if I use clock() or something similar in two threads that are executing on separate cores, how far off the time stamps could be. If I could count on the time stamps on two different cores being within about 25ms from each other, that would be ideal. I just haven't really been able to figure out a good way to measure what the difference is between the two. I have done some more research and it appears that timeGetTime in the Windows API is not effected too much by being called by separate cpu cores. I am going to try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a satisfying answer, you need to answer the following questions first:

- How closely do the images need to match?
- How much jitter / error in timestamping can you live with?
- How much latency you expect between the moment the image is captured and the moment your thread receives it and can timestamp it?
- Is the latency expected to be about the same for both cameras?

If you have a mostly static scene, then you can live with higher timestamping jitter and latency than if you have a very dynamic scene.

Precision of the `clock()` is not going to be the main factor in your timestamping error -- after all, you should care about relative error (how close the timestamps are between two threads), not absolute error (how close the timestamp is to the true atomic time).

On the other hand latencies, and especially jitter in latencies, between the hardware and your thread will drive most of the error in your timestamping. If you can find a way to get a timestamp in hardware or at least in the driver, it will go a long way toward improving accuracy of your timestamps.